# Morphism that conserve sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $\{ a_i \}_{1,n} \in \mathbb{(R⁺)}^n$  verifying $\sum_i a_i = 1$ and $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$.

Is there any function (or family of function) $f$ that verifies :

1. $\sum_i f(a_i) = 1$
2. $f(a_1) > f(a_2) > \dots > f(a_n$)

?

If there is, can you give an exemple. If not, why ?

From 2., I know that f is decreasing over $\mathbb{R⁺}$ but I can't find any of those functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have such functions only for each $\ n>1\ $ separately but not any function which would work for any two different values of $n>1$ at the same time.

For each natural $\ n>1,\ $ such function

$$ f_n : \mathbb R_+\rightarrow \mathbb R\ $$
is unique; here $\ \mathbb R_+\ $ can be interpreted as $\ (0;\infty)\ $ or $\ [0;\infty),\ $ either way.

> 

For $\ n>1,\ $ we let

$$\ f_n(x) := \frac 1{n-1} - x $$

> 

**REMARK:**  Such functions $\ f_n\ $ don't exist for $\ n>2\ \ $
**if**   we want
     $\ f_n:\mathbb R_+\rightarrow\mathbb R_+.$

> 

The **uniqueness** of each function $\ f_n\ $
(for $\ n>1)\ $ follows from its affine property:

$$ f_n(a)+f_n(d)\ =\ f_n(b)+f_n(c) $$

whenever $\ a\ b\ c\ d\,\in\,\mathbb R_+\ $ and

$$ a+d\ =\ b+c\ \le\ 1 $$

This is easy to prove (a good exercise), and it shows
that there is a constant $\ C_n\ $ such that
$ f_n(x) = C_n-x.\ $ Obviously, it must be
$\ C_n = \frac 1{n-1}.$

> ***A final remark.***   The case $\ n=1\ $ is different, there is no uniqueness due to its triviality. The decreasing condition is meaningless for $\ n=1.\ $ Thus different arguments are not glued together, they are totally independent. Hence no uniqueness.

Comment: Why would such functions would not exist for $n>2$ on strictly postive numbers ? Could you give me some insight over the underlying algebraic reason ?

Comment: These functions are unique! Just apply the respective (unique!) function (use its defining formula) to certain concrete arguments, and you will see that you end up with negative values.

Comment: Sorry, you meant that they are the only functions _verifying those properties_. That is so mind-bending that it does not exist for just these conditions on positives numbers.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics.